# Why decreasing pattern in following residual plot

Tags: time-series, python, linear

I'm using 'hour.csv' from https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning/tree/master/first-neural-network/Bike-Sharing-Dataset for linear regression.

After creating dummy variables for categorical variables and making sure to avoid dummy variable trap, I scatter-plotted y_predicted on X axis and residuals on Y axis and found a decreasing trend in it. I'm adding its image and my code below. Could someone pl. explain why it's happening and how to fix it? (Pl. see my code which is below the image. It's python code and I've used sklearn. I've omitted 'import' statements for the sake of brevity).

[image]

`dataset = pd.read_csv('hour.csv')
z = dataset
X = z.drop(['instant', 'dteday', 'casual', 'registered', 'cnt'], axis = 1)
y = z['cnt']
t3 = pd.get_dummies(X, columns = ['season'])
t3 = t3.drop('season_4', axis = 1)
t3 = pd.get_dummies(t3, columns = ['mnth'])
t3 = t3.drop('mnth_12', axis = 1)
t3 = pd.get_dummies(t3, columns = ['hr'])
t3 = t3.drop('hr_23', axis = 1)
t3 = pd.get_dummies(t3, columns = ['weekday'])
t3 = t3.drop('weekday_6', axis = 1)
t3 = pd.get_dummies(t3, columns = ['weathersit'])
t3 = t3.drop('weathersit_4', axis = 1)
X = t3
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 2)
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,y_train)
reg.score(X_test,y_test)
y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(y_pred, y_test - y_pred)`

Comment: If cnt means it is a count (therefore non-negative) what you see is hardly surprising. You need to use a model suitable for such data like Poisson regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this approach is wrong and an example of the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

As suggested by the name (and confirmed by the link you included), these data are a time-series. Modelling these without accounting for the covariance structure violates the [independence of observations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions) of ordinary linear regression. It is therefore no surprise that the diagnostic plot looks strange. However, trying to fix it will not fix the underlying problem.

Instead, you could model these data with an [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average), or a [mixed model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) with an appropriate covariance structure.

You may also want to have a look at the [time-series tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series).